# Find all $P$ with $P(x^2)=P(x)^2$

Tags: polynomials

The following problem is from Golan's book on linear algebra, chapter 4. I have posted a proposed answer below.

**Problem:** Let $F$ be a field. Find all nonzero polynomials $P\in F[x]$ satisfying

$$P(x^2)=[P(x)]^2.$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach is generally good, though the execution might perhaps leave something to be desired.

Let $F$ be of characteristic different from $2$; we may assume $p(x)\neq 0$. Let $a_nx^n$ be the term of lowest degree. Then the term of lowest degree of $p(x^2)$ is $a_nx^{2n}$, and that of lowest degree in $p(x)^2$ is $a_n^2x^{2n}$, so $a_n=a_n^2$. The only solutions in a field are $0$ and $1$ (they must be roots of $x^2-x$), and since $a_n\neq 0$, we conclude $a_n=1$. Now assume that there exists $m\gt n$ such that $a_m\neq 0$, and pick $m$ to be the smallest such. Then $p(x) = x^n + a_mx^m + (\text{terms of higher degree})$, so
$$p(x^2) = ax^{2n} + a_mx^{2m} + (\text{terms of higher degree}),$$
whereas
$$\begin{align*}
p(x)^2 &= (x^{n} + a_mx^{m} + (\text{terms of higher degree}))(x^{n} + a_mx^{m} + (\text{terms of higher degree}))\\
&= x^{2n} + 2a_mx^{n+m} + (\text{terms of higher degree}).
\end{align*}$$
Since $n+m\lt 2m$ and $2a_m\neq 0$, this is a contradiction. Therefore, $p(x) = x^n$. And since these clearly "work", it follows that the only polynomials with the desired property are the nonnegative powers of $x$ and the zero polynomial.

Now assume that $F$ is of characteristic $2$. If $p(x) = a_0 + a_1x+ \cdots + a_nx^n$, then
$$\begin{align*}
p(x^2) = a_0 + a_1x^2 + a_2x^4 + \cdots + a_nx^{2n}\\
p(x)^2 = a_0^2 + a_1^2x^2 + a_2^2x^4 + \cdots + a_n^2x^{2n}.
\end{align*}$$
Therefore, if $p(x^2) = p(x)^2$, then $a_i^2 = a_i$ for all $i$, so $a_i=0$ or $a_i=1$ for all $i$. Thus, $p(x)\in\mathbb{F}_2[x]$. And all of these work. Thus, for fields of characteristic $2$, the polynomials that work are all polynomials over the prime field (all coefficients equal to either $0$ or $1$).

Answer (score 2):

Assume first that $F$ is a field with characteristic not equal to 2. The only ones are 1 and $x^n$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Let $a_n$ denote the coefficient of $x^n$ in $P$. We see immediately that all $a_n=0$ for odd $n>0$. Examining the constant coefficient, we see $a_0=a_0^2\Rightarrow a_0=1$ or $a_0=0$.

Now proceed by induction. Consider the case where $a_0=1$. Assume we have shown $a_n=0$ for all $n<k$, $n\neq 1$. We will show $a_k=0$. If $k$ is odd, we are done. If $k$ is even, the coefficient of $x^{k}$ in $P(x^2)$ is $a_{k/2}$, so it is 0. We evaluate $[P(x)]^2$ and ignore higher order terms, and see

$$(a_kx^{k}+1)^2=a_k^2x^{2k}+2a_kx^k+1$$

and the only way for the coefficient of $x^k$ to vanish here is for $a_k$ to be 0.

The case with $a_0=0$ is similar. Assume we have shown $a_n=0$ for all $n<k$. The coefficient of $x^{2k}$ in $P(x^2)$ is $a_{k}$. If evaluate $[P(x)]^2=[...a_kx^k]^2$ and ignore higher order terms again, we get $a_k^2x^{2k}$. So $a_k=1$ or $a_k=0$. If $a_k=0$, we continue the induction. If $a_k=1$, we factor $x^k$ out of the original polynomial and are reduced to the first case.

In a field of characteristic 2 however, I believe that any polynomial with all coefficients equal to 0 or 1 works. Just use the "freshman's dream." Further, because equating constants on both sides gives $a_n^2=a_n$, these are the only ones that work.

Comment: If $p(x) = x$, then $p(x^2) = x^2$, and $(p(x))^2 = x^2$. But you claimed it was only even powers of $x$... So I don't "see immediately" that $a_n=0$ for all odd $n$. In fact, for any $k$, $x^k$ works, since $p(t) = t^k$ means $p(x^2) = x^{2k} = (x^k)^2 = p(x)^2$.

Comment: Oops. Let me fix this.

Comment: Also, the answer *may* depend on the field? If $F=\mathbb{F}_2$, then $(a+b)^2 = a^2+b^2$, so for example $p(x) = x+1$ has the desired property.

Comment: That is disconcerting. It appears I will have to think about this a bit more.

Comment: You can "delete" the question (leave a note both in your question and in the answer, the latter so that high rep users can see what the problem was), then later edit it an "undelete it" once you are happy with it.

Comment: I think I fixed it when the characteristic isn't 2. Thinking about that case now...

Comment: You still have the left-over error of thinking the odd coefficients must be zero, when you say (second line, third paragraph) "if $k$ is odd we are done".

Comment: No, not every polynomial works in characteristic $2$. Consider the field $\mathbb{F}[\alpha]$, where $\alpha^2=\alpha+1$. Then $x+\alpha$ does not work.

Comment: Ok. I believe everything is finally fixed up. Fingers crossed.

Comment: Same field $F[\alpha]$. What about $x^2+\alpha x$? Constant term is $0$, so you claim it will work...

Comment: I keep forgetting there are fields of characteristic 2 that aren't Z_2. Thanks for all the help.